# How to make a more specific image search with google api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-custom-search

I am trying to make a search to find images related to ***"Paris in 1500"*** but I get some images which are not related specifically.

I tried using: "***Paris + France + 1500***" or "***Paris in 1500***" yet I get images which are only related to the word "***Paris***" or Simple "***France***".

I believe I should be search for a string including the `" "` but it is not working.

This is how I am using their api to search for my string:

```
    var termS = "Paris";
    var date = "1500";
    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
        q: termS + " in " + date,
        alt: "json",
        searchType: "image",
        cx: "MY_CX",
        key: "MY_API",
        rights: "cc_publicdomain",
        filter: "1",
        num: "10",
        fileType: "jpg",
        imgType: "photo"
    },
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){    
            $(".my_images ul").append('<li><img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '"></li>');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you try `+Paris +France +1500`? Gets me 10 images at least in normal image search, all related

Comment: no I haven't, why should I use the + before the single words?

Comment: 1500 could be anything. it could be part of a timestamp used to title the picture or an address, etc. i would try "year 1500" or "1500AD", etc, or include other words like "history" or "historical" to indicate that it is a time.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. ok I will try building a different string

Comment: @Pekka웃 actually that link you sent says "The + operator has been replaced. To search for an exact word or phrase, use double quotation marks: hacker "news" And I did specify on my question that I would like to include the " "

Comment: How are the "" not working, does the code break or are you not getting the desired results?

Comment: google seems to remove my "" and use special characters, I even tried using the uncodeURI http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: `q: '"Paris" "in" "1500"'` doesn't work?

Comment: Off topic, your web site is not working for me. Something about an expired certificate. Just FYI

Comment: @Pekka웃 no that string is not working. Also what web site isn't working? That needs a API key which I didn't put in here

Comment: I mean your web site, in the profile. The "imagine everything" spinner just spins endlessly

Comment: @Pekka웃 I will simply change the string as suggested on the comments here. Yet now I am trying to resolve this other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666007/how-to-change-a-custom-google-search-if-functiondata-is-empty